# Is it possible to deploy a maven artifact straight to a webserver?

Tags: version-control, deployment, builds, maven

Say I have my project that looks like

```
/src/main/java/...
/src/main/resources/...
/src/main/webapp
pom.xml
```

And I have this stored in my version control, Git/SVN etc.

My artifact has a signature like

```
<groupId>dwj.me</groupId>
<artifactId>some-project<artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

If I have a nexus server running, I can deploy my project to nexus and packaged copy of the project is available and can be used as a dependency in other projects.

If I want to deploy this project to a webserver, currently I first need to check the project out from version control, and then use a build command to deploy it to my specific webserver.

What I'm wondering is if there is a way to avoid having to check the project out from version control, ie. deploying using the artifact id only.

Additionally there are likely to be configuration properties in `/src/main/resources`, is it possible to set these properties without having to check out from version control?

Comment: Everything is possible when you ask on the right StackExchange site!

Comment: So far I see, what you need is not nexus server. You need a Jenkins :-)

Comment: I  have found this searching on [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569710/how-can-i-automatically-deploy-a-war-from-nexus-to-tomcat)

Answer (score -1):

This is more specific to  **Continuous Integration (CI)**  and Continuous Deployment. To achieve this  **Jenkins, Bamboo tools**  are recommended and easy  *integration with your repositories, build script and deployment on respective server*

for Jenkins you can visit https://jenkins.io/ : This would guide you of installation, setup and configuration.

Comment: this doesn't even attempt to address the question asked

Comment: @gnat : This is one of the way to achieve it